# Assembling a combinatorial tree in R

Tags: r, tree

I'm trying to build a Combinatorial Tree model, where the initial leaf is the first 6 digits.  The 2nd level is all possible combinations of 5 digits of the parent's 6 digits. Then the 3rd level is all possible combinations of 4 digits of it's parent's digits.  This pattern continues until 6th level, which is composed of only single digits.

So my question is there a way to generate a tree in this fashion?  I've been searching for examples of basic trees in R and have wound up empty handed.  Any advice would be much appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can get something like that using this:

```
f <- function(x)
{
    if(length(x)==1) return(c(value=x))

    c(list(value=x), child=lapply(seq(x), function(i)f(x[-i])))
}
```

Example:

```
> f(1:3)
$value
[1] 1 2 3

$child1
$child1$value
[1] 2 3

$child1$child1
value 
    3 

$child1$child2
value 
    2 


$child2
$child2$value
[1] 1 3

$child2$child1
value 
    3 

$child2$child2
value 
    1 


$child3
$child3$value
[1] 1 2

$child3$child1
value 
    2 

$child3$child2
value 
    1
```